# Is there a way to find out how many elements are in a Queue

Tags: java, queue, element

As the title says I want to know if there's a way to find out how many elements there are in a queue(similar to String.length()). i'm using the weiss nonstandard ListQueue
thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not familiar with "weiss nonstandard ListQueue", but if it implements `java.util.Collection`, then you can use `size()`.

Comment: @trooper pending approval of my edit suggestion, here is the link: http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~weiss/dsj3/code/weiss/nonstandard/ListQueue.java

excerpt: `implements Queue<AnyType>`

Comment: Good luck on your homework!! :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as the documentation says there is no method for getting the length.

[Documentation](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~weiss/dsj3/docs/weiss/nonstandard/ListQueue.html#method_detail)

Instead you can create your own method for it, extend this ListQueue class and override or create another method(Wrapper method) for the enqueue method in which increase the counter every time you call enqueue method and declare a static variable for keeping the counter.
After increasing the counter call the super class enqueue method as normal.

and declare the method where you can access the static variable for the counter.
In this way you will be able to get the length of the queue.

Answer (score 0):

In java, you can use `size()` method to determine the number of elements in a queue. For example,

```
public Integer countQueueElement()
{
 Queue<Integer> q = new Queue<Integer>();
 q.add(1);
 q.add(2);
 q.add(3);
 return q.size();
}
```